# Facebook login callback returns name but not email address

Tags: javascript, facebook-login

I'm using Facebook login in the simplest way, and getting a call back response:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v6.0&appId=881911462250499&autoLogAppEvents=1"></script>

<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                   FB.api('/me',  function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    });
});

}
</script>
```

I log the response to the console and receive the name and id, but not email address. How can I get the email as well? Upon researching it, it should get it by default, am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok got it, I was confused and it shoudl be here:

```
FB.api('/me', { locale: 'tr_TR', fields: 'email,name' }, function (response) {
```

Comment: Hi, you can mark your answer as the correct answer I guess.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Fb docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web), This is how you do it.

```
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {  // Called with the results from FB.getLoginStatus().
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);                   // The current login status of the person.
    if (response.status === 'connected') {   // Logged into your webpage and Facebook.
      testAPI();  
    } else {                                 // Not logged into your webpage or we are unable to tell.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this webpage.';
    }
  }


  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '{app-id}',
      cookie     : true,                     // Enable cookies to allow the server to access the session.
      xfbml      : true,                     // Parse social plugins on this webpage.
      version    : '{api-version}'           // Use this Graph API version for this call.
    });


    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {   // Called after the JS SDK has been initialized.
      statusChangeCallback(response);        // Returns the login status.
    });
  };



  function testAPI() {                      // Testing Graph API after login.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    });
  }
```

You can check login status in this way.

```
  function checkLoginState() {               // Called when a person is finished with the Login Button.
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {   // See the onlogin handler
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }
```

By default, fb allows only basic permissions. What you require is additional permission, hence you have to request it this way.

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  // handle the response
}, {scope: 'email,user_likes'});
```

You can read more about it [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v6.0). Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you very much I tried to use FB.login as well, with the scope included, and yet I just don't get the email property within the response. I don't understnad why.
Thanks in advance